# É possível criar um campo data que seja Cross-Browser?

Tags: html, navegador-de-internet, cross-browser

Alguém sabe como fazer com que o `<input type="date">` funcione em todos os navegadores?

No *Google Chrome* funciona normalmente, consigo passar o parâmetro no formulário, recebo na variável e jogo no `insert`, o problema é que no *Internet Explorer* ele não captura essa data. Existe algum código que faça esse método valer em todos os navegadores?

Comment: Vc está usando `<input type="date" />` ?

Comment: sim estou!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Não são todos os browser que suportam `<input type="date" />`.

Veja aqui a [lista de compatibilidade de browsers](http://www.html5browsersupport.com/html5-element-comparison?id=) para a tag `<input type="date">`